# Paperclip migration in rails does not change table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I ran the following line (& got a response) to create a migration for paperclip, as per the documentation

```
[imageuploading!tme]$ rails g paperclip user avatar

create  db/migrate/20120824134503_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb
[imageuploading!tme]$ rake db:migrate
==  AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers: migrating =====================================
-- change_table(:users)
-> 0.0338s
==  AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers: migrated (0.0339s) ============================
```

The migration ran successfully, but as you can see it changed nothing in the users table.

The relevant bit of migration code is the standard:

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.has_attached_file :avatar
end
```

Paperclip is successfully installed as a gem

Why does the has_attached_file helper (?) not work?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just update your existing table migration with:

```
t.string  :avatar_file_name,               :limit => 100
t.string  :avatar_content_type,            :limit => 30
t.integer :avatar_file_size,               :default => 0
t.string  :avatar_fingerprint,             :limit => 50
```

Comment: I can try that - I was simply following instructions in the Paperclip quickstart (which are clearly wrong)